# Carte de Sejour France effective date

Tags: resident-permit

Trying to find when one is actually deemed a resident of France. We have just submitted the paper work for our carte de Sejour, we have lived here for 3 months, we are British citizens.

We have been told that a decision will be made within two months and if approved we will have a 5 year temporary cds, aas insurance etc,

so when do we start this process? Now or when we receive our cds.. just wary that we may not be covered by insurance if we are deemed as FRENCH residence now and we haven’t advised our UK insurance, or whether we need to transfer our cars now, seems like a minefield

fter 5 years we can apply for a permanent residency.

We need to transfer our UK registered cars to France as well

Any advice would be really appreciated